# Case with In, when GROUP BY

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hello I have a query in mssql that looks like this:

```
select .,.,.,.,
CAST(ROUND(SUM((CASE WHEN Action.PersonId IN( 10274,9999)  then Action.WorkMinutes else 0 END)/60.0),2)AS DECIMAL(8,1))
from Action
inner join ...
```

This works but now I need to replace `IN(10274,9999)` with something like:

```
IN(
select people.PersonId
  from people 
 inner join TeamMember on TeamMember.PersonId = people.PersonId
 where TeamMember.TeamId=83)
```

Unfortunately this gives:

> Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an
>   aggregate or a subquery.

I have a feeling there is an easy fix for this but I just can't  think of it right now.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? MySQL/SQL Server/PostgreSQL?

Comment: can you paste your whole query that gave this error?

Comment: See if https://ask.sqlservercentral.com/questions/94930/cannot-perform-an-aggregate-function-on-an-express-1.html works, I Did not understand

Comment: Paste you whole query, the nature of the error doesnt really point to what you have shown

Comment: long story short, you can't use a subquery in a sum, you need to find a way to work around it

Comment: Edited start post, about mssql.
I am fairly sure the error message is from the part described in my post and I have gotten a working fix so I will not past my whole query. It is a big one and I think it would just complicate the question unnecessarily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message clearly states you cannot place a subquery within an aggregate function. The following will work as a work-around in SQL Server:

```
select CAST(ROUND(SUM((x.y)/60.0),2)AS DECIMAL(8,1))
from Action
CROSS APPLY (SELECT CASE WHEN PersonId IN (select people.PersonId
                                           from people 
                                           inner join TeamMember 
                                           on TeamMember.PersonId =   people.PersonId
                                           where TeamMember.TeamId=83) 
                         THEN WorkMinutes else 0 END) x(y)
```

Comment: Never seen this before, worked lika a charm.
Thanks!